# Can the tensor $v_1 \otimes v_1 + v_2 \otimes v_2$ be written as a dyadic tensor $w_1 \otimes w_2 \in V \otimes V $?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

Let $V$ be a $ \mathbb{Q}$-vector space with basis  $ B = (v_1,v_2)$.
Can the tensor $v_1 \otimes v_1 + v_2  \otimes v_2$ be written as a dyadic tensor $w_1 \otimes w_2  \in  V  \otimes V $? If so, find such a representation.

My way of thinking is that a dyad is a tensor of order two and rank one, and is the dyadic product of two vector. Should I have to check it that this product is commutative and distributive? Or do I have to check the rank of the product? I'm totally struggling with this exercise. I would really appreciate any kind of your help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we think of those tensors as quadratic (or bilinear) forms on ${\mathbb Q^*}^2$, then $v_1\otimes v_1 + v_2\otimes v_2$ is positive definite, i.e. for any $(a,a)\in {\mathbb Q^*}^2$, we have $$(v_1\otimes v_1 + v_2\otimes v_2)(a, a)=(v_1(a))^2+(v_2(a))^2>0$$ for any $a\not=0$. But $$(w_1\times w_2)(a,a)=w_1(a)w_2(a)=0$$ for $a\in \ker w_1\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 3):

If that would be the case then, il would exist $\alpha_{ij} \in \mathbb Q$ such that

$$\begin{cases}
w_1 &= \alpha_{11} v_1 + \alpha_{21} v_2\\
w_2 &= \alpha_{12} v_1 + \alpha_{22} v_2
\end{cases}$$
with
$$w_1 \otimes w_2 = (\alpha_{11} v_1 + \alpha_{21} v_2) \otimes (\alpha_{12} v_1 + \alpha_{22} v_2) = v_1 \otimes v_1 + v_2  \otimes v_2$$

As $v_i \otimes v_j$ is a basis of $V \otimes V$ this implies
$$\begin{cases}
\alpha_{11}\alpha_{12} &= 1\\
\alpha_{11}\alpha_{22} &= 0\\
\alpha_{21}\alpha_{12} &= 0\\
\alpha_{21}\alpha_{22} &= 1
\end{cases}$$

Which is not possible.